# C calculating sum correctly

Tags: c++, sum

I can get the sum every time the user inputs an integer until either a negative number or non-integer is inputted.  Problem is my sum calculations are off. I.E user putting 1000; sum outputs 1111, then user inputs 2000, it adds up to 3333. Just any advice is appreciated. I'll still experiment around with my coding.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int j , i = 0, k = 0,number;
double sum = 0;
cout << "Enter Positive integer number: ";
while(cin >> number)
{

    cout << endl;
    if( number < 0)//test if the number is negative
    {
        cout << "Ending program since user has input a negative number" <<endl;
        break;
    }
    int temp = number;
    int p = 1;
    while( temp > 0) //counting number of digits
    {
        sum = sum+temp; //Sum attempt.
        temp /= 10;
        p *= 10;
        i++;

    }

        cout << sum << endl;

    j = i % 3;
    p /= 10;
    while( i > 0 )//display integer number with 1000 seperator
    {
        //this is giving me error
        cout << char ((number/p) +'0');
        number %= p;
        p /= 10;
        i--;
        k++;
        j--;
        if ((k % 3 == 0 && i > 0)||(j == 0 && i > 2) )
        {
            cout <<",";
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "This program will exit if you input any non-integer characters\n";
    cout << "Enter another integer number: ";
}

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you know what the loop `while (temp > 0)` is doing? With 1000 as an example, you get `sum = 0 + 1000`, `sum = 1000 + 100`, `sum = 1100 + 10`, and finally `sum = 1110 + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm a doofus lol ;/.  I'll rework on my sum calculation carefully with these loops.

Comment: It's just a simple mistake; happens to the best of us. I just wasn't sure if that was your intention or not. Are you trying to add together all the digits of the number, like 1234 = 1+2+3+4 = 10?

Comment: Thanks, I just moved my calculating sum BEFORE the while loop, and now it adds the sum perfectly! :) So if the user inputs 1000, sum is 1000, then user inputs 2000, I want it to be 3000 sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to output an integer number with commas inserted at 1000 boundaries.  ie: 1000000 would be displayed as 1,000,000.

This being the case, the easiest way to approach it might not be involving maths but simply to get a string representation of the int (`atoi()` for example) and count through that.  From the back, count forward three chars, insert a comma, repeat until you run out of string.

The specifics of string handling are left as an exercise for the reader - looks like it's his homework after all.   ;-)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, I just moved my sum calculation "sum = sum+temp;" before the while loop and calculates correctly.  Thanks for your advice on atoi function.  I actually have one more thing to do, and that is to add a decimal to these integers.  I started trying to code the comma's first.